# How to make fancybox resize to custom created iframe size

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to make the fancybox dimensions match the content size of a "manually created" iframe.

I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/ystLD/3/

But it doesn't work and now I'm kinda stuck here.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "manually created" `iframe` has the disadvantage that fancybox doesn't really know what `type` of content is dealing with. I would rather open fancybox with the option `type: "iframe"`.

Then, the only way I can think you can re-size fancybox according to the contents of the `iframe` is hard-coding the dimensions inside the page opened within the `iframe`, either in the `html`, `body` or a wrapper container like

```
<html style="width: 800px; height: 650px;">
```

then you could use the `beforeShow` callback to get the dimensions of the `iframe` like

```
  beforeShow: function(){
   this.width = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').width();
   this.height = $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('html').height();
  }
```

If you don't own the opened page and you cannot hard-code its dimension, you still can try getting the `innerWidth()` and `innerHeight()` of the `html` or `body` tag, but it can be really buggy as you can see in this [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaKbU/6/)

Here is the answer that worked for someone else https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776520/1055987

Comment: Really useful. One caveat though. This jQuery code ignores any whitespace that's styled to the element but you can just add those values back to prevent your content from bing cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the width and height to the attributes of the iframe since you're creating it manually anyways.

```
.attr({ name: 'blah', width: '500px', height: '500px' })
```

If you want something that will exactly match the size of the page you are fetching then it's a pretty tedious task since an iframe is pretty much like opening a browser window. You would have to determine the size of the widest div and such programmatically by analyzing the structure. Also, you would have to determine if the page uses a responsive layout and use a specific size for that.