# Resize fancybox width after visiting link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I created a fixed width fancybox defined on the parent page like so:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    width: 650
});
```

I have a link that can be clicked within the iframe that pops up that directs to a new page that is 850px wide. I need the FancyBox to adjust up to that width. How can I do this? I've tried using the autosize:true function but that does not seem to do the job.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10776520/1055987 ... you always would need to set dimensions inside the new iframe though. Then, from within the iframe, you could call the `parent.$.fancybox.update()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can do:

```
$(".fancybox").css({"width" : "850"});
```

right after your Fancybox call.

Comment: I'm very new to javascript since I mostly do PHP right now. Where would I implement this code? Would I call it onclick of the anchor tag? So <a href="" onclick="$(".fancybox").css({"width" : "850"});> kinda thing? Or where else to put it? Thank you!!

Comment: You shouldn't call this inline. You should be calling the event handler from your file, and then you would put the fancybox resizing call right after that. You'll also need to define the width of your iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this, assuming that the new content has a size set:

```
$('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-outer, #fancybox-content').css('width', 'auto');
$.fancybox.center();
```

Comment: for latest version
$('.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner, .fancybox-content').css('width', 'auto');
        $.fancybox.reposition();

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

```
$('#fancybox-content').width(850);
```

To resize the width of the fancybox at any time.