# determining fancybox iframe body's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, height

I have a fancybox showing an iframe with some content from another domain.

I want to determine it's content's height when it's loaded.
If I use

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

(in the iframe content document's javascript), it gives me the right height in case there is a vertical scrollbar or the screen becomes higher.
However if the iframe becomes smaller, that just gives me the previous height.
I thought to solve this by using

```
document.body.height
```

then but that returns undefined.
Is there another way to get the body's height (since the iframe content's body actually has the right height if I inspect it through the browser's developer tools? Or might it have something to do with the fact that the function is called in $(window).load?

Thanks

Comment: Due to the [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) you can't retrieve properties on a third party page. If you can control the page within `iframe`, you can find some alternatives from this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/1169519).

Comment: possible duplicate of [set fancybox height with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876787/set-fancybox-height-with-jquery)

Comment: I pass it to the domain showing the fancybox through postMessage, so it can. I just need a way to determine the body's height inside the iframe so I can pass that.

Comment: JFK I beg to differ. That question is about setting a fancybox height manually when you know which height it's supposed to be. This one is about getting an iframe actual content height within the frame itself (as it turned out I didn't always send the right height through). It seemed best to split the questions as one doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the other.